# Verifying a solution for a Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, solution-verification

We have $r$ and $\theta$ are polar coordinates in 2D and $h = r^2 \dot \theta$. Verify that
$$
u(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{\theta^2+c^4}}{ac}
$$
where $c$ is any constant solves
$$
\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} = \frac{1}{a^4u^3}.
$$

I initially tried differentiating $u(\theta)$ twice and seeing if it was equal to $\dfrac{1}{a^4u^3}$, but this didn't work.

---

My working:
I have worked out by differentiating $u$ twice that
$$
\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} = \frac{c^3}{a(\theta^2+c^4)^\frac{3}{2}}.
$$

Subbing in for $u$, I get that
$$
\frac{1}{a^4u^3}=\frac{c^3}{a(\theta^2+c^4)^\frac{3}{2}}.
$$

Since
$$
\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2} = \frac{c^3}{a(\theta^2+c^4)^\frac{3}{2}} 
= \frac{c^3}{a(\theta^2+c^4)^\frac{3}{2}}, 
$$
$u(\theta)$ is a solution of the second order differential equation stated.

Is this correct ?

Comment: There's a number of unclear points here. Is $h$ a constant or a function? Is $\dot{\theta}=d\theta/dr$ or are both $r,\theta$ functions of time $t$? How is $u$ supposed to relate to $r$? (I would _guess_ $u=1/r$ which is a common substitution in orbital mechanics problems but that's a major point of context to omit.)

Comment: @Semiclassical $h$ is a constant as defined in my post. Anything with a "dot" is a function of time. And $u = \frac{1}{r}$

Comment: You start by saying that differentiating $u$ twice doesn’t work, but then you go on to show that it does actually work. What’s the problem here?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I meant that I initially differentiated $u$ twice and expected it to equal the RHS but it didn't, so my second step was to sub in for $u$ on the RHS and I reached the same equation as I showed in my post. My question is have I answered the question of verifying $u$ is a solution correctly ? And is this the most efficient method ?

Comment: Seems OK to me - this is indeed verifying that it is a solution. I don’t think there’s a more efficient method

Comment: @DavidQuinn Okay thank you. Sorry for not making this clearer earlier.

Comment: You put a differential geometry tag here. Why? This looks like it may have come from an application of Clairaut's relation, but you've removed any semblance of geometry from your question. You said $h=r^2\dot\theta$ but forgot to say that $h$ is constant.

Comment: @TedShifrin This was clarified in my first comment above. I didn’t think all that context was initially relevant since it was just verifying a differential equation solution

Comment: My point, then, was that the differential geometry tag is inappropriate. But it seems you've answered your own question completely.